# File Server - Hostname vs. FQDN

Tags: networking, hostname, share, file-server, fqdn

I have a problem with a File Server at Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Operasion System. When my user browse a network share with FQDN she can't see the files, but if she browse it without FQDN (only with hostname) can see them. Although this problem sometimes can occur in reverse cases.

What might be a problem? I've attached two pics about the problem (sorry for auditing the domain name). Please write anything what you know about this issue.

without FQDN:
[image]

with FQDN:
[image]

---

I think it's a DNS problem, because yesterday we met the same problem at another server. Any idieas what should I do to resolve this problem? Thanks advance!

Comment: If you create file3 in the share with fqdn, it appear on the share with the hostname? I want to be sure you dont land somewhere else

Comment: Dear Gerald,

Yes, the users are in the correct locations at both (with FQDN and without FQDN). This problem had overseered by other System Administrators too, and the result had the same at every tries.

Comment: what would be ping results for (1)fqdn (2)without fqdn ? same ip ?